# Is the set size preserved by intersection when the original sizes are the same?

Tags: elementary-set-theory

Let $A$ and $B$ be two sets with the same size, i.e., $|A|=|B|$. Let $C$ be a given set. Is it true that $|A \setminus C|=|B \setminus C|$?.

**My try**

I know that when $|A|=|B|$ then $|B \setminus A|=|A \setminus B|$ but I do not know how to use this fact to show the claim or reject it.

Comment: Try a few examples  with small cardinalities (2 or 3).

Comment: If $C=B$ is disjoint from $A$, then...

Comment: One can find a counterexample rather easily, e.g. $A=\{a\}$, $B=\{b\}$ and $C=B$. Then $|A|=|B|=1$ but $|A\setminus C|=|A|=1$ and $|B\setminus C|=|\emptyset|=0$ (as already mentioned by FShrike)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is not true. Take $A:=\{0\}$ and $B=C:=\{1\}$. Then $|A\setminus C|=|A|=1$ and $|B\setminus C|=|\emptyset|=0$.